# How do you sanitize a string to pass a regex?

Tags: javascript

I have a regex validation I need my string to pass.

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$/
```

I want to create a function that sanitizes the string for it to pass the regex.
I thought of doing something like

```
string.replace(/^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$/,"");
```

Except I need to invert the above regex.

I tried to look up how to invert a regex but nothing seems to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `string.replace(/\W/g,"")`. Also check [this web site](https://regex101.com/) i always use it to test regular expressions, it also has hints on the right bottom

Answer (score 0):

Negate the collection using ^ inside the []

```js
const str = `abc*ç%ABC&(/())12345=?`

const newString = str.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z-]/g,"");

console.log(newString)
```